# Xcode 4.5 MainStoryboard for iphone 4/4s

Tags: iphone, xcode

I just upgraded to **Xcode 4.5** and noticed that my apps do not appear correctly in the **MainStoryboard**. The **MainStoryboard** seem to have ***increased in height***. I suspect it has something to do with the new iPhone 5. How can I create new apps with the with the MainStoryboard set to the height for the iPhone 4 and 4S?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the view controller(s) on your storyboard, select the view controller properties panel and set the simulated-metrics Size property to Retina 3.5 Full Screen.